# Velocity equivalent of jQuery marginLeft

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I had a question for anybody familiar with the jQuery plug-in velocity.js.  I'm trying to get an item to slide in from the left.  Here is the equivalent jquery code:

```
$el.animate({marginLeft: '-150px', height: '20px'})
insert()
$el.animate({marginLeft: '0px', height: '20px'})
```

This does what I want, I'm trying to do the same thing with velocity, I'm currently using translateX as such:

```
$el.velocity({translateX: '-150px', height: '0px', duration: 0})
insert()
$el.animate({translateX: '0px', height: '20px'})
```

The problem is the item spawns at 0, moves to -150, and slides back in to 0.  How can I get it to spawn at -150?

**EDIT - Solved**

If anybody else is interested, I had to set the overflow property to hidden:

```
$el.css({marginLeft: '-150px', height: '0px', overflow: 'hidden'});
insert()
$el.velocity({marginLeft: '0px', height: '20px'});
```

Also, the insert() function is native to the Vue.js MVVM framework.  That was probably confusing, it inserts the element: http://vuejs.org/guide/transitions.html

Comment: When you solve your own problem you should post an answer and accept it so it is clear to others that the issue is already resolved.

Comment: @JamesMontagne yes I was going to but because I'm a noob stackoverflow won't let me answer my own question until 8 hours after i posted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See "$.css()-like Transform Setting" in the Velocity FAQ: https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/47.

Might be of use. Either way, I'm confused by your question and your code samples :-p.

Comment: Sorry about poorly worded question.  Basically the exact problem I was having was just that the 'overflow' property was not set to hidden.  I was trying to do sort of a 'slideDown' style thing.  I edited my answer to be more correct.  Either way, good link.